# How to determine concavity without inflection point?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to determine this function concavity:
[image]

2=0 is a contradiction, so we have no inflection points on this  function, so ¿How could I determine the concavity if I have no inflection points?

This function's graph:
[image]

Should I take the "0" as a refered point, then evaluate the f''(x) (for example) with f''(-1) and f''(1) to determine the concavity?

Because on that case, I can effectively determinate the concavity, but is this legal?
¿why I'd take the "0"? On this case, I've take the "0" just because I've seen the graph previously.

Comment: The fact that $x=0$ is not in the domain of the given function (and its derivatives), does not mean that there cannot be a sign change in the derivatives...

Comment: How do you define "concave function"? For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function defines this only for the case of a convex domain and $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is not convex.

Comment: But in the intervals $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ a sign-change of $f''(x)$ cannot occur. So, in fact, it is sufficient to calculate $f''(-1)$ and $f''(1)$

Comment: so, a inflection point could be the number where the f'(x) is indeterminated? ("0" on this case)

Comment: No, there is no inflection point at $0$, and there isn't any one anywhere else either. The "level of concavity" (for the lack of better words) gets greater as $x$ get closer to zero

Comment: ok, that's why I can take the "0" as a referred point to use f''(-1) and f''(1) to determine the concavity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $x=0$ is the critical value since $f^{\prime \prime} (0) $ is undefined.

Now use this to divide out your intervals into two intervals.

$(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$.

Pick a test point on each interval and see whether the $f^{\prime \prime}(test value)$ is positive or negative. If it's positive then that mean $f$ is concave up in that interval, and if it's negative then it's concave down.

For example, on the interval, $(-\infty, 0)$ , pick $x=-1$ then $f^{\prime \prime}(-1) = -2$, hence concave down.